# Connection Error for SQL Server Debezium for Apache Kafka

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to set up CDC on my SQL Server and send messages to Apache Kafka. I am getting the following error:

```
The 'database.names' value is invalid: Cannot be empty.
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:123)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:107)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.processExtraArgs(ConnectStandalone.java:81)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.startConnect(AbstractConnectCli.java:150)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli.run(AbstractConnectCli.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:112)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
The 'database.names' value is invalid: Cannot be empty
```

I have tried adding a database.names propery to my connector.properties file but that did not work.

I have a connector.properties file and it has database.dbname=AdventureWorks2022. Not sure why its saying the value is missing?

Comment: Can you share your connector.properties?